# Minkowski metric and definition of coordinate differentials?

Tags: relativity, metric-tensor, notation

This is probably a really silly confusion I have about the definition of “coordinate differentials”, which I thought were things like $dx,dy,dz$
  etc. The Minkowski line element $$ds^{2}=c^{2}dt^{2}-dx^{2}-dy^{2}-dz^{2}$$
  defines the Minkowski metric $$\left[\eta_{\mu\nu}\right]=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
c^2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}\right).$$
 Using index notation, the line element can be written as $ds^{2}=\eta_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$.
  In textbooks I have seen the terms $dx^{\mu},dx^{\nu}$
  called “coordinate differentials”, which seems OK except $dx^{0}=cdt$.
  I realise this is trivial, but is it correct to call $cdt$
  a “coordinate differential”? To me it looks like a coordinate differential $dt$
  multiplied by $c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is largely just terminology. Strictly speaking the coordinate is $ct$ not $t$, and of course $d(ct) = cdt$. In any case we usually choose units where $c = 1$ and just ignore it.

Comment: Of course! I should have realised.

Answer (score 5):

Each set of coordinates comes with its own set of coordinate differentials and its own coordinate expression for the metric tensor:

Given coordinates $(t,x,y,z)$, the coordinate differentials are $dt,dx,dy,dz$ and
$$
(\eta_{\mu\nu})=\begin{pmatrix}
c^2&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&0\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&0&0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Given coordinates $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$, the coordinate differentials are $dx^0,dx^1,dx^2,dx^3$ and
$$
(\eta_{\mu\nu})=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&0\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&0&0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
(Strictly speaking, we should probably use different symbols for the metric tensors, eg $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ and $\tilde\eta_{\mu\nu}$).

As
$$
x^0=ct\\x^1=x\\x^2=y\\x^3=z
$$
obviously
$$
dx^0=cdt\\dx^1=dx\\dx^2=dy\\dx^3=dz
$$